# bootstrap 5 form if valid

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

i want run some js if my form is valid.
i use bootstrap 5, i found this. but dont now how to add 'if form.is_valid {}'

```
<script>
(function () {
'use strict'
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.requires-validation')
Array.from(forms)
  .forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
    }

    if (form.valid(){ # but this not working } else { #this working }

    // already tried using .valid , .is_valid, .isValid but no one work
  
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
</script>
```

i also found this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>

function validate_form2(form_id){
        var form = $( "#" + String(form_id) );
        form.validate();
        $( "button" ).click(function() {
            if (form.valid()){
                loading_screen()
                form.submit()
            }
        });
        
    }
```

but the problem if i using that, the message 'please fill this form' are inside the input. not using tooltip.

thanks

Comment: Why dont add an else to `if (form.valid())` and call your tooltip?

Comment: i tried using `if (form.valid(){ # but this not working } else { #this working }`

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution,
to check the form are valid or not using `form.checkValidity`

```
<script>
(function () {
'use strict'
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.requires-validation')
Array.from(forms)
  .forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
    }

    // the solution are here
    else { do something }

    
  
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
</script>
```